# Calculate coordinate for a point along given line

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapserver

Using Openlayers or plan Javascript, how would i get the coordinate of a point that is 500 meters along this line?
Im trying to calculate the coordinate (lat long) x meters along a given line

Example coordinate for a line :

```
[59.8736731,10.803402600000027]
[59.9319572,10.688514700000042]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line between two points on a round planet isn't necessary a straight line on a flat map, and a meter in map units isn't necessarily a meter on the ground (it wil be somewhere on the map, in the  case of an ESPG:3857 projection it's at the equator only).

But let's assume you would like the point to be on the straight line on the map, even if the shortest distance between the points may be a curve on a flat map (over short distances the difference will be very small), and you are using a meter based projection such as EPSG:3857 or one of the UTM zones.

```
var distanceAlongLine = 500;

// convert lon and lat points to map projection
var point1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon1, lat1], mapProjection);
var point2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon2, lat2], mapProjection);

// calculate length in nominal map units using pythagoras
var lineLengthInMapUnits = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(point2[0]-point1[0],2) + Math.pow(point2[1]-point1[1],2) );

// adjust for the average real resolution of map projection along the line
var adjustment = ( ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection,1,point1) +
                   ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection,1,point2) )/2;

var lineLengthOnTheGround = lineLengthInMapUnits * adjustment;

// calculate a point along the line based on distance to total length ratio
var pointOnLine = [ point1[0] + (point2[0]-point1[0])*distanceAlongLine/lineLengthOnTheGround,
                    point1[1] + (point2[1]-point1[1])*distanceAlongLine/lineLengthOnTheGround ];

var lonlatOfPoint = ol.proj.toLonLat(pointOnLine, mapProjection);
```